# Why did moving variables out of HashMap's insert method scope solve a deadlock?

Tags: rust, hashmap, deadlock

`OB_HM` is `Arc<Mutex<HashMap<...>>>`

This caused the deadlock at very first iteration:

```
let mut OB_HM__:HashMap<u8, (f64, f64, f64, f64)> = HashMap::new();
    for i in &p {
        OB_HM__.insert(
            *i, 
            (
                OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].0, OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].1 
                R[&i].0,
                R[&i].1
            )
        );
    };
    let mut OB_HM = OB_HM__;
```

And this solved it:

```
let mut OB_HM__:HashMap<u8, (f64, f64, f64, f64)> = HashMap::new();
    for i in &p {
        let x = OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].0;
        let y = OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].1;
        OB_HM__.insert(
            *i, 
            (
                x, y, 
                R[&i].0,
                R[&i].1
            )
        );
    };
    let mut OB_HM = OB_HM__;
```

Why so? I had mere intuition but I need to understand the internals behind it. I'm guessing it has to do with how Rust creates `tuple`s or how the method `insert` works?

And a side question about `insert` - why does it require `;` EOL when it's the only instruction inside a `loop`?

Comment: Because the lock is held for the duration of the top-level statement, which means you tried to hold the same lock twice. When you extracted locking to variables, you also extracted both locks to their separate statements, so the first lock is released before the second one is acquired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This caused the deadlock at very first iteration [...]
> Why so?

Shortly, because of [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension).

Generally<sup>1</sup>, `OB_HM.lock()` create a new object, a *mutex guard*.
This is a temporary object and it implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait (allowing *autoderef*).

De-referencing the mutex guard creates a borrow of the inner object (i.e., the `HashMap`) that extends the lifetime of the guard itself.

Therefore, the mutex guard is not dropped until the end of entire function call (i.e., `insert`) and so the `Mutex` is not unlocked. Since you have two *lock*s in your function call expression, that generates a deadlock.

Maybe a toy-example might help to understand: [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d79a5f9f0fc21f3372130431eee42da).

From the above,

```rust
foo(mutex.lock().value(),  // <--- first lock
    mutex.lock().value()); // <--- second lock
```

produces a deadlock because both `lock`s are released only after the entire expression `foo` (the function call) has been evaluated.

Indeed the output:

```
MutexLock!       // <--- First lock
MutexLock!       // <--- Second lock
 > !DEADLOCK! <  // <--- Two interleaved locks! Deadlock!
foo: Call!       
                 // <--- Now the function ends
MutexUnlock      // <--- And only at the end the mutex are unlocked!
MutexUnlock
```

*Note that*, this is independent from *tuple*s.

The "working" solution works because:

```
let x = OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].0;
let y = OB_HM.lock().unwrap()[i].1;
```

the temporary expression of `lock` lasts for the entire statement.
So after `x` has been assigned, the temporary `lock` is released. Allowing `y` to acquire it without deadlocks.

---

> And a side question about insert - why does it require ; EOL

Because of rust syntax I guess.

From here: [`loop syntax`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#infinite-loops)

```
loop BlockExpression
```

where `BlockExpression` is defined as zero or more statements.

Expression are accepted only as [expression-statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements.html#expression-statements) (that is, with `;`).

---

1. It might depend on your `Mutex` type.